# Australia/Sydney time zone in java does not consider DST

Tags: java, timezone, dst

I have created a java class which takes a given  date and time and then converts it according to other time zones.
I have to consider DST also while conversion.
I read it that when we use only code for time zones then java wont evaluate according to DST but if we use full time zone names then DST is considered.
My problem is that the above mentioned approach works fine for the other time zones except for Australia/Sydney. 
i also read this : the ambiguity of using 'EST' for both (US) Eastern Time and (Australian) Eastern Time has been a pitfall in Java since forever.
But this should atleast consider DST when TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney").useDaylightTime() is returning true.

any help would be appreciated.

here is my java code :

```
String timeStamp="2014-08-22 20:13 "+"MST" ;

    try
    {
            SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm z");
            SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy, HH:mm z");
            SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
            Date datetime =sdfIn.parse(timeStamp);
            System.out.println("default without any zone  "+sdfOut.format(datetime));
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST"));
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
            System.out.println( sdfOut.format(datetime));
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));       
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));
            //it displays correct time but it display EST time zone
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("AET"));
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));                
            //display time with DST consideration
            System.out.println("DST time considerations");              
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Phoenix"));
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
            System.out.println( sdfOut.format(datetime));                               
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));  
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));
            sdfOut.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/NSW"));
            System.out.println(sdfOut.format(datetime));


            System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney").useDaylightTime());
            System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/NSW").useDaylightTime());
            System.out.println(TimeZone.getTimeZone("AET").useDaylightTime());


        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

output :
`default without any zone  Saturday, 23 August 2014, 08:43 IST
Friday, 22 August 2014, 20:13 MST
Friday, 22 August 2014, 22:13 EST
Saturday, 23 August 2014, 08:43 IST
Saturday, 23 August 2014, 03:13 GMT
Saturday, 23 August 2014, 13:13 EST
DST time considerations
Friday, 22 August 2014, 20:13 MST
Friday, 22 August 2014, 23:13 EDT
Saturday, 23 August 2014, 08:43 IST
Saturday, 23 August 2014, 04:13 BST
Saturday, 23 August 2014, 13:13 EST
true
true
true`

Comment: solved : AET itself is using DST. Thats why their is no change in using short form n long from. unlike AET, other time zones return false  
:TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Sydney").useDaylightTime().. GMT,EST are not considering DST

Answer (score 2):

Australia is in the Southern Hemisphere.  So in Australia, August is winter, and Daylight Savings doesn't apply.  Try it again with a date between October and March.

Comment: +1 - Crikey Bruce, do you mean that isn't autumn everywhere now?  :-)

Comment: sorry, but not change when i used  month from october to march

Comment: it is still showing same time in both the cases.. is their any chance that while using "AET" only, java has considered DST

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sydney switches from +10 to +11 in _their_ _summer_. In OP's opinion, Java's `Australia/Sydney` timezone doesn't account for that.